# How to add some JavaScript functions before Ajax begins

Tags: 7, forms

How do I add some JavaScript functions before Ajax begins, with FAPI?

```
$form['submit'] = array(    
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Upload',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_submit_key_dump'
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hello user871, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. What do you mean by "adding some JavaScript functions"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I whant to hide some divs. $('.mydiv').hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a javascript file to a form using the `#after_build` property:

```
$form['#after_build'] = array('my_js_add_function');

....

function my_js_add_function($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_add_js(...);
  return $form;
}
```

Using `#after_build` instead of adding the js in the form definition makes sure that the JS is added even if the form is gotten from cache.

In the JavaScript file you can add whatever jQuery you want to, a click handler on the submit button should do what you want.

Comment: Attaching the JS is one thing, but getting it to run onclick of an object that Drupal's ajax.js has already "hijacked" doesn't seem to register.

Answer (score 6):

"beforeSubmit" handler attached that way will be executed right before Ajax request:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.ReplaceWithAnyTextYouWant = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // 'edit-submit' is the element ID where you execute the #ajax.
      Drupal.ajax['edit-submit'].options.beforeSubmit = function(form_values, element_settings, options) {
      // If cancel is clicked, do not continue submitting.
      if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?')) {
          return false;
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You could perform some pre-submit validation of the user input, and even cancel form submission by returning false

Here is a [good example](http://www.gruta-pixel.com/blog/2015/07/drupal-7-how-execute-custom-javascript-submiting-ajax-form)

'edit-submit' - is the element html ID of submit button with '#ajax' settings. 'edit-' prefix is attached to the key of your form array item containing triggering element (submit button in your case).
For $form['my-submit'] = array(...), html ID of the resulting button will: "edit-my-submit".

JS file with code shown above, could be attached to your form in form constructor:

```
$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module') . '/js/file.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom module; using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) I have added a JavaScript file to one of my content type forms. If you need more details, say it.

Comment: Hello @user709,  I have a form, that post file to the server throw ajax, and i need execute some jquery comands like $('.mydiv').hide(); befor ajax began send file to server.